Ghostscript with PHP
I have this code:
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../controller/funcoes.php';
require_once '../controller/constantes.php';
$pdf = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf('C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf_reader\view\arquivo.pdf');
$n_pages = $pdf->getNumberOfPages();
for($i=0; $i < $n_pages; $i++){ 
    $fileName = time();
    $pdf->setPages($i)->saveImage($filename.".jpg");

}
echo "$i páginas criadas";

?>

I have the ImagickMagic and ghostscript(10.03.1) installed also, with the system variable path with this value: C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.03.1\bin
When I run the script, it returns this error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs"
-sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"
-dPrinted=false "-sOutputFile=C:/Windows/TEMP/magick-f36-98eDD03_kdd4tvDDH1D1tWRY0Sfb%d"
"-fC:/Windows/TEMP/magick-cThxTwLomvy44ooiiQjsUW5SNzn02SKN"
"-fC:/Windows/TEMP/magick-Gpve-WcS4mc1A3mCM3_sJbPjzz7WRlIQ"' (O
sistema n�o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. ) @
error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/516 in
C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf_reader\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-image\src\Pdf.php:44
Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf_reader\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-image\src\Pdf.php(44):
Imagick->readImage('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #1 C:`your
text`\xampp\htdocs\pdf_reader\view\livro_features.php(5):
Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf->__construct('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2
{main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf_reader\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-`image\src\Pdf.php
on line 44

I don´t understand whats is going on, since the file is in the path of the constructor method.
I someone can help, I appreciate very much

On Windows the Ghostscript executable is not called 'gs'. It is gswin<32|64>(c).exe ImageMagick is trying to use the Linux named executable which, obviously, won't work, even though you have added the Ghostscript binary path to your $PATH environment variable. The fact that the path is in your PHP code doesn't affect the name that ImageMagick uses to execute the Ghostscript binary. You need to alter the plugin configuration for ImageMagick, and I can't tell you how to do that (or rename the Ghostscript binary or create a link or something).

Actually, Ghostscript is licenced under the AGPL version 3. There isn't anything which prevents 'commercial use' in the licence. As long as you stick by the provisions of the licence you can use Ghostscript commercially.
